# Is it possible to programmatically check for a new connection using PySerial?

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21050671/how-to-check-if-device-is-connected-pyserial/49450813) post which asks a similar question. However, the answers were not what I expected to find so I'm going to try asking it a little differently.

Let's assume a function `searching_for_connection` will run indefinitely in a `while True` loop. It that function, we'll loop and preform a check to see if a new connection has been made with `/dev/ttyAMA0`. If that connection exists, exit the loop, finish `searching_for_connection`, and begin some other processes. Is this possible to do and how would I go about doing that?

My current approach is sending a carriage return and checking for a response. My problem is that this method has been pretty spotty and hasn't yielded consistent results for me. Sometimes this method works and sometimes it will just stop working

```
def serial_device_connected(serial_device: "serial.Serial") -> bool:
    try:
        serial_device.write(b"\r")
        return bool(serial_device.readlines())
    except serial.SerialException
        return False
```

Comment: Is the device expected to reliably respond when you send it a carriage return?

Comment: Yeah the device that I'm connecting to should be sending responses to carriage returns

Comment: You may have to wait for a defined period to allow for the inevitable latencies.

Comment: That's something I hadn't thought of. Any recommendations for a sleep period?

Comment: Well you have to allow for your `b"\r"` single character to make it through the driver software and over the line. (btw what is your baud rate?). Then you have to allow for the device to generate a response (this is the difficult one) and then allow for the response. (so what is the response? is it another `b"\r"` or more?)

Comment: Baud is either 9600 or 115200 depending on some other factors. Response should just be `b"\r"` as far as I'm aware

Comment: So, for 9600 baud, you need to delay `1.04ms` for each `cr`, so `2.08ms`, plus the internal latency of your device. It may be a suck-it-and-see, but you could try a fixed `time.sleep(0.01)` after the `.write()` and before the `.readlines()`.

Comment: Between that and a reboot of both devices it seems to be working. Throw an answer below and I'll accept it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest having a delay to allow time for the device to respond.

```py
import time

def serial_device_connected(serial_device: "serial.Serial") -> bool:
    try:
        serial_device.write(b"\r")
        time.sleep(0.01)
        return bool(serial_device.readlines())
    except serial.SerialException
        return False
```