# What would be the best way to handle a serial disconnect?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

Ideally I would like to call a function when the USB port is disconnected while open, but I can't find if such thing is possible. While my python program runs, its opens up serial port `self._serial = serial.Serial(self._serialPort, 9600, timeout=1)` where `self._port = '/dev/tty.usbserial-FTBNNWBM'` when the device is disconnected nothing happens, until the program tries to send a command and fails.

I would like to be able to call `disconnectHandler()` when the device is disconnected.

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21050671/how-to-check-if-device-is-connected-pyserial answer your question

Comment: What exactly do **you** consider "best"?

Comment: What happens during the disconnect? Do you get thrown an exception ?

Comment: That question does not answer it. Sorry. The thing I would like to happend was maybe like an interrupt would happend When the device was unplugged, with a callback to a disconnect handler